# update field value

Tags: entities, hooks

how to update a field value of one content type node when a field value of another content type is changed using hook_node_presave?

for eg: 
           content type | field name    | field value | updated value

```
       product      | product_stock |      10     |     24
       Add stock    | stock value   |      14     |
```

Comment: sorry for the example. i mean to say: content type field name field value updated value product product_stock 10 24 Add stock stock value 14

Comment: sorry for the example. i mean to say:

Answer (score 0):

- First of all you need to link the two nodes - check out this module - http://drupal.org/project/references. It provides a field (add to one content type) that stores reference (of another reference type) ie. the nid
- So 2 nodes will now be connected.
- Next, in your [hook_node_update](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7) check when node of the first content type is updated - get the nid of the related node from its node reference field => node_load(nid) => change whatever value you want => node_save(nid).

Hope this wokrs for you. All the best!

Comment: how to get get the nid of the related node from its node reference field. Plz reply. I think it will work

Comment: function my_module_node_presave($node){
  if($node->type == 'add_stock') {
    
 
 $product = $node->field_stock_value['und'][0]['value'];
 drupal_set_message($product);
 $addStock = $node->field_reference['und'][0]['nid'];
 $p_node = node_load($addStock);
 
 drupal_set_message($p_node);
   
 
 
  }
  
}

Comment: i had done this, written above. I had created a custom module my_module and inside that my_module_node_presave. But it gives an fatal error.

Comment: If you don't know laready then first off all install drupal.org/project/devel. Then you can check your node object(or anything in any function) using dsm($node). In there you will find the nid from node reference field. Hoe far have you got till now?

Comment: And I think hook_node_update might(I say might...not sure) be the place to do this.

Comment: Check in your server log file what the error is.

Comment: thanks SGhosh for your answers. I sussefully completed my task.

Comment: thanks SGhosh for your answers. I sussefully completed my task.

Comment: oh sure.. I will. :)